# WEbResponse throws 500 Internal server error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have many times successfully implemented reading data from web pages using technique like this:

```
  WebRequest req = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
  WebResponse resp = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse(); etc.
```

.........

However, this time the WebResponse throws an internal error. Otherwise, I can browse the parameter path.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Below you stated you got a null ref exception.  Did you get a null ref (catch) or did you get a WebException with a status of 500 and the body of the error coming from the server contains object null ref in the error description?  Those are very different things ...

Comment: I got null ref exception in the webException coming from the server..stating further that debug mode should be enabled to get more specific exception..AS I am not in control of that web page I cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be any number of reasons.

You should try to catch the error and see if you can get any further details from the response. Perhaps try adding the code below and see if that provides any further details:

```
catch (WebException webex)
{
Console.WriteLine("Unable to perform command: " + req);

String data = String.Empty;
if (webex.Response != null)
{
   StreamReader r = new StreamReader(webex.Response.GetResponseStream());
   data = r.ReadToEnd(); 
   r.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine(webex.Message);
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not mentioned that I already tried code catching the WebException.. I am just getting generalk exception like :

Comment: like Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I am not in control of that page, so I am not able to get more specific information about the error..

Answer (score 0):

Probably its not creating the request, **WebRequest.Create**, 
there can be a proxy issue if you are behind any proxy, i got the same problem that my code was unable to connect to any path but it was browsing fine.

Comment: is path expecting some get/post data? looks like the problem is at path end, not on your end.